# How to write (if, if, if) else if none

Tags: java, boolean, if-statement

I'm trying to make a group of `if` statements, in which each `if` will print given some argument is true, but an `else` that will only print `if` none of the `if`s were returned. I don't think an `else if` would work in this case.

I have some code (the colors are just as examples):

```
boolean any=false;

if(redStage==2)
{ any=true; System.out.print(redComplete); }

if(blueStage==2)
{ any=true; System.out.print(blueComplete); }

if(greenStage==2)
{ any=true; System.out.print(greenComplete); }

if(any==false)
    System.out.print(noneComplete);
```

Is there anything I can do to eliminate the need for a separate boolean to check whether any of the if's arguments were true?

Edit:
(I just noticed what may be confusing. The code im using isn't actually using return. Instead, it is printing out the results, which means more than one thing can be returned.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you need to processes the stages independently from one another, and more than one can be complete at the same time, your code is as good as it can be.

*What follows is my answer to your original question:*

You don't need the boolean. Your code is equivalent to:

```
if (redStage   == 2) { return redComplete; }
if (blueStage  == 2) { return blueComplete; }
if (greenStage == 2) { return greenComplete; }
return noneComplete;
```

This makes use of the fact that each `if` body contains an unconditional `return`. If this wasn't the case, you could phrase the construct like so:

```
if (redStage == 2) {
   // redComplete
} else if (blueStage == 2) {
   // blueComplete
} else if (greenStage == 2) {
   // greenComplete
} else {
   // noneComplete
}
```

Comment: That's what I was gonna say.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this works, actually. It seems to always return nonComplete, even if one or more of the stages are 2

(I just noticed what may be confusing. The code im using isn't actually using return. Instead, it is printing out the results, which means more than one thing can be returned.)

Comment: @colinbr96: If you need to processes the stages independently from one another, and more than one can be complete at the same time, then your original code is as good as it can be.